# A2billing AGI Issue

Tags: asterisk, voip, billing

Quick question: Whenever I make changes in agi-conf in the web interface of A2billing, those changes are not made whenever I listen to the dialplan that the agi-conf is placed in. what could be the problem? I am always sure to ensure I edit the correct agi-conf file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk wont take your changes to `.conf` files into account until it is reloaded, or the server rebooted.

you can do it from the Asterisk CLI

```
sudo asterisk -rvvvvv
```

then at the prompt

```
reload
```

You can reload asterisk directly using the following command:

```
sudo asterisk -rx "reload"
```

Answer (score 0):

Those changes imidiatly apply to new calls of a2billing.

If you not see changes in call, check that you use correct agi-confX section(see debug log)